# How do I create multiple Box2D Dynamic bodies that won't push each other.

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm creating a multi-player platform game in Cocos2D (objectiveC). I create dynamic bodies for the players as it applies gravity and platform collision however I don't want the players to be able to push each other characters (while fun, too much grief). What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `b2Filter` data of an object, setting the `groupIndex` of bodies to the same, negative number means they don't collide with each other. `b2Filters` are set on a per fixture basis. ([LINK](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972))

```
//Objects with these fixtures won't collide as they have the same, negative, groupIndex
fixture1Def.filter.groupIndex = -1;  
fixture2Def.filter.groupIndex = -1;
```